# How can block azure aks get-credentials --admin and allow azure aks get-credentials only on azure?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, config, admin

Use `azure aks get-credentials --admin` can get kubernetes admin config file and `azure aks get-credentials` can get only user config file on azure.

How to set something to deny user run `azure aks get-credentials --admin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, be default they cant run it, unless they have specific azure permissions. so by default you dont have to do anything. they shouldnt have this specific permission:

```
Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/listClusterAdminCredential/action
```

which they would get if they are contributor for the AKS resource or resource group. They need this permission to get user credentials:

```
Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/listClusterUserCredential/action
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am not clear that if anyone can run that command, anyone can control the cluster by admin role?

Comment: Yes, once 'azure aks-get-credentials --admin' command is executed, you gain the full access to the cluster as a cluster admin.

Comment: What happens behind the scene when you are executing 'azure aks get-credentials' with different arguments (--admin or --user), is well explained under this Github issue here:[https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/505#issuecomment-403170563]